# Integrate Cunit ino team city

Tags: teamcity, cunit

How could I integrate cunit to team city? 
I want to see result on team city correctly?
I found [this](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/eclipse-integration/branches/Calcutta-4.5.x/jetbrains.teamcity.core/src/jetbrains/teamcity/core/test/CUnitParser.java)

Can I use that for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a perl script that transforms output of cunit executable to [teamcity service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages). you can see it in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zarezadeh/6267606).

For running this in teamcity, you should pipe cunit output to this script and then everything will be fine.